# I don't even have any AS3 code?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, error-handling, flash-cs5

And I'm still getting these errors! All I've got, is simple MovieClip that contains NO code... I mean, ABSOLUTELY NO CODE, and I'm perfectly sure about this :S Maybe I have to change something in AS preferences? Here, take a look. And YES, that's all.

[image: Here, take a look]
[image]

Comment: @Kevin - right click and view image

Comment: @shane - very nice, when I hovered and got nothing, I figured, well, nothing was there - seeing it now.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025626/flash-cs5-as3-weird-xml-errors

Comment: search for `expecting xmltagendend` - there are a plethora of hits

Comment: do you mean `>`? I suppose it's because AS compiler thinks of `<` in the `if` statement `if(currentFrame==2 && startFrame.y<1000)` as of `XML`'s opening tag, right? But WHY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this post is now over a year old, but I saw anecdotal evidence from a random forum site which solved the issue for me, so I thought I'd at least get it logged on SOF, to hopefully save others the same frustration.

I have no explanation as to how/why the problem exists, but luckily was able to easily pin point the change in my project which seemed to be the cause.

Basically I created a MovieClip which consisted of only 3 TLF Textfields, all using an embedded font. The 3 TextFields text were:

"Total"
"="
"00"

The problem appears to be the TextField which contains only the equals character "=".

As soon as I removed it, all of the above errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Check for other AS files in the same path. That's where the code is in AS3, rather than putting them on movieclips you create separate files for each class.

Comment: There are no nested MovieClips, if that's what you mean :S

Comment: No no no. Check the folder with the .fla, there should be more folders / .as files. That's where your code are.

Comment: Oh... Yes, I've got lots of AS files in the same directory, but none of them is longer then 100 lines, to say nothing of 5587!... Although, I've gotta check out lines 51 and 54 :SS Right?

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems like it's a XML file.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that it's not XML (at least because I don't know it), but who knows... Maybe it's generated automatically? :SS Or kinda that :S

Comment: OK - In Keyboard1_1, line 54, there's a syntax error. The line 5587 seems to be caused by your syntax errors and invalid XML names. Try fixing those and I think it should work.

Comment: That's the piece of code where error is supposed to be:

    if(currentFrame==2 && startFrame.y<1000) {
    startFrame.y+=5;
    speed1.y+=5;
    speed2.y+=5;
    speed3.y+=5;
    speed4.y+=5;
   }

Comment: Can you post the XML file here?